# How do I add a contributor to a resource group without allow him to access any resource he has not created previously

Tags: azure, azure-management

I have some resources that I do not want a new contributor to be able to delete or even view. Is it possible to add this new contributor in such a way that he can create new resources and use them but restrict any other resource that he has not created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. If you need such restrictions you should create a new resource group for the user.